# Using payment terminal with Electron and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuejs3

I am making a checkout application in Vue.js and will be using electron to run it on desktop. I am running into the issue now that I can't get the integration with the payment terminal to work. I have a Worldline Yomani attached to the pc via USB (and to the internet through ethernet). I don't know how to send a number to it so that a customer can pay straight up without first needing to enter it. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I can't find any real data on doing this online.

If you have worked with any payment terminal of any brand, how did you do this?

Regards
Dany

Comment: That sounds more like an issue which can be solved by contacting Worldline's customer support rather than something we can help you with...

Comment: I thought there would be a general way to interact with these payment machines, or rather hoped. That would have made it much easier and more compatible with different payment machines.